# Craft CMS pull-in/nest field into a matrix

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system, craftcms

I'm loving Craft CMS and how flexible everything is. I'm wondering if the following situation is possible...

When creating a [matrix field](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields), after adding a `Block Type`, rather than filling out each field manually, I would like to pull in another field that I have previously created.

For example:

*My original field could be `button` which has various inputs about position, style, text etc.*

*In my matrix field, I would create a `Block Type` of button (or whatever) and in the `fields` just select `button` field rather than having to duplicate it every time. *

I'm keen to do this to have a centralised field... so that in the event I want to adjust the button field (say to have a new option, like animation or something)... this would filter down to every matrix that uses the field.

I assume this would require a plugin of some form to achieve this?

Comment: FFR, Craft CMS has its own Stack Exchange site at http://craftcms.stackexchange.com ;)

Answer (score 4):

The [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo) plugin for Craft CMS lets you do exactly this. It's basically a Matrix field with some additional features, like the ability to use global fields within your block types, and to have nested blocks.